# network IP addresses monitor widget

Tags: networking, hosts

Is there a widget that shows all current hosts (IP adresses) in a list? I am not talking about a network bandwidth meter widget.

Comment: i am talking about a desktoo widget. Yea im femiliar with netstat, tho i need a widget that auto updates itself. Was hoping such a thing `d be around : ) thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is. Use screenlets. [`sudo apt-get install screenlets`] = for ubuntu. It has a widget that execute a command and outputs the data in your desktop as a widget in a box. The application screenlets update the command (execute actually) every second if you want to. 
You can insert into that widget the command `netstat -natp`

Another solution before i discovered screenlets was a script:
The link for the script is:
http://innovative.recomm.org/?p=6

The advantage of the script is that you can call it through remote shell

Good luck